# First Integral and types of maximal curves

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $\left( \begin{array}{c} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} y \\ \sin(x) \end{array}\right):= v\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)$.

We need to find a First Integral and show where constant, injective and periodic curves flow. Now the first part was easy. The second part I just don't know how to solve. It is clear to me that $sin(\pi)=0$ so $v\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$ if $x=j\pi$ with $j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y=0$.

So we found the critical points and the places where constant curves are. But how do I find the Intervalls where perdiodic/ injective curves are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One formulation for the first integral is
$$
F=\frac12y^2+1+\cos(x)=\frac12[y^2+(2\cos(x/2))^2].
$$
For a periodic solution you need inflection points on the solution curve, that is, points where $y=\dot x=0$. Which means that the constant value of $F$ has to be inside the interval $(0,2)$. For $F>2$ the velocity $y=\dot x$ always is non-zero and has the same sign, thus steadily increasing or decreasing $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Still I'm sorry, but I don't understand how you got to the interval $(0,2)$ and how you used $F$. Could you explain that? I would very much appreciate it. :)

Comment: I chose the integration constant in $F$ so that I could write it as sum-of-squares. If the solution to $\ddot x-\sin x=0$ is periodic, then there has to be local maxima, where $\dot x=0$, so that $F=2\cos(x/2)^2$ at those points, which limits the values that $F$ can take.

Comment: I still don't really understand but am thankfull for your response and that you took the time.